# Can you give me some clarification about the concept of "representation" in a REST service?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, architecture

I am studying REST architecture reading this article: https://templth.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/designing-a-web-api/

But I have some doubts about it:

I understand that REST does not depend directly on HTTP, but that HTTP is a smart way to implement a REST web API.

I also understand that the focal point of a REST web API is the **resource** concept, which is something like a programming element that manages data, state, performs processing, and that a resource is represented by a URL. For example, something like this: http://mybank.com/banking/accounts/123456789
can be a resource representing a home banking account.

Moreover, I know that with REST a resource is accessible on the Web from a URL and we can interact with it using a **predefined set of methods** and that if my REST API is based on the use of HTTP, this set of methods are the methods provided by the HTTP protocol (`GET`, `PUT`, `POST`, `DELETE`).

I think all of that is pretty clear for me.

What I have some doubts about is the concept whereby the REST web API **provides a set of resources that exchange representations**. I think I understand what a resource represents, but after reading the previous article, I can't understand exactly what is meant by **"representations."**

Further, the posted article says that:

> The formats of exchanged data correspond to representations. The
>   latter provides for the managed data kind. We can notice that a
>   representation defines a structure of data and isn't linked to a
>   particular format such as `JSON`, `XML` or `YAML`. This concept is called
>   variant.

What is meant by: **formats of exchanged data**?  Can anyone explain exactly what the previous paragraph means?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very such for regarding the article!

A representation corresponds to the data exchanged between the client and the RESTful services. You can distinguish to kinds:

- Structured ones that are data-oriented and include a set of fields. For example, a contact with fields lastName and firstName.
- Unstructured ones that corresponding to content like binary (images, zip, ...), simple texte, ... It mainly corresponds to media content and UI

Another concept comes along with representations, the variants (also called media types). It defines the format used for the representation content. For example, JSON, XML, HTML, PNG, ...

Here is a sample of a structured representation with variant JSON:

```
{
    "firstName": "a name",
    "lastName": "..."
}
```

The sample of an unstructured representation with variant PNG is the content of à PNG file itself.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry